# how insert into different tables (sqlite)?

Tags: sqlite

How i can insert values into different tables after 'case when'?

```
select case when state=1 then ('insert into table1 insert into table2') else '0' end from mytable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot embed `INSERT` inside of `SELECT`.

There are 2 ways to do what you want:

1. Do it the right way. Execute `INSERT` and determinate target table in your application code. That is use `if` statement in C/C++/Java/C#/... code, not in SQL.
2. A more tricky way, but without coding it into application would be to create a `VIEW` in your database. It doesn't matter what is the `SELECT` query in the view. It can even be simple `SELECT 1;`. Then create two `TRIGGER` objects for that view, that will be triggered on insert into that view. Each trigger should have a `WHEN` statement defined for a proper `new.state=0` and `new.state=1`, so when you perform insert into the view, only one trigger will be fired - the one with matching state. Then in that trigger do the actual `INSERT` into desired target table. As I said - it's a tricky way. I would strongly recommend first approach.